# Build Visual Studio C++ project in docker

Tags: windows, visual-studio, docker

Is it possible to build MSVCPP 2015 project inside docker? I found, that docker started to support windows containers, here is repo: https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/ . But it is focused on .NET applications and servers, but I want to build desktop exe application. Is it possible?

Comment: Here's a Dockerfile that builds an image with the C++ Build Tools: https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/tree/master/msbuild

Comment: We are currently building inside a Docker windows container using Visual Studio 2013 (we installed the entire suite). Building the image isn't as smooth as we would have liked due to installation bugs in VS 2013 update 5 (hangs and what not), but apparently this has been fixed in VS2015. Our build farm has been migrated to using these containers and it has been very stable.

Comment: can not build this image on OSX :( getting error unkown blob

Comment: Is your Dokcerfile available? For VS2013

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible. There is a document here that I have used as a starting point: [Install Build Tools into a Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container).

Comment: To be clear, this is installing the VS 2017 build tools, not a 2015 environment as was asked in the question. However 1) I believe it is possible to install the 2015 tools from that 2017 environment 2) the 2017 tools should be backwards compatible and may work with the 2015 project.

Comment: It is good as a starting point, can you tell me how I can build and compile up from there, please?